# Looking to embed node links within CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes, navigation

I would like to be able to embed node links within CKEditor but have the plugin use a view or table to display the content of the type of my choosing.

[Linkit picker](http://www.drupal.org/project/linkit_picker) looked like exactly what I wanted but I found it was not compatible with version 3.x or even 2.x of [Linkit](http://www.drupal.org/project/linkit).  [I tried the 2.x dev version of linkit picker as well.]

Another similar module was [CKEditor Link](http://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link), but this uses auto-complete and I would like paged display, or something that uses views so I can customize the output.

Comment: What will you be using the output for? Will your users end up choosing a node and that becomes a link (like how ckeditor link works now)? Or is it just there for some other visual purpose? I'm just struggling to understand the intention of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @marblegravy , it must be visually the same as the old system which uses a table/paged view to select a node and insert a link into a textarea on a node/add form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything out there that works exactly how you're describing. The only thing that is similar is https://drupal.org/project/nodepicker but it doesn't have a stable release any more and may have the same compatibility issues as Linkit picker. You may be able to pick it up and get it working if you're up to the challenge though.

It sounds to me though that you're just trying to make your new site built with Drupal behave like your old site made in something else. It's like complaining that your new car doesn't stall at the traffic lights like your old car did. ;)

I'd install ckeditor link and ckeditor 4.x and just convince the people you are huilding it for that this is the most efficient way to link up your content.

Otherwise I suspect you'll be building something custom.